# React: How can I make a component wait for a value in my case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**The problem:**

So basically I created a context which is used to store the logged in user data so I can easily use it accross my application. I created a component which verify if the user is logged in or not, or if the access to the content of it is restricted to administrator only. The problem occurs when I try to access a page which uses SecureCard. It basically says that user is empty so it just redirect me to the home page, but it's clearly not empty because I can see my username in the header of my website. So my question is why is that.

If you need any extra code or some more context just tell me.

**Some context:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./App";
import {UserProvider} from "./contexts/UserProvider";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <UserProvider>
            <App/>
        </UserProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Where I think  it originates from:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {ReactSession} from "react-client-session";
import {getUserByToken} from "../utils/accounts";

const UserContext = React.createContext(null);

export function UserProvider({children}) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        _id: "",
        creation_date: "",
        rank: "",
        username: ""
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ReactSession.get("token") && (user._id === "" || user.rank === ""  || user.username === ""  || user.creation_date === "")) {
            getUserByToken().then(resp => {
                if (!resp?.error) setUser(resp.message);
                else ReactSession.remove("token");
            });
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
}

export const UserConsumer = UserContext.Consumer;
export default UserContext;
```

**Where the problem happens:**

```
import {Card} from "react-bootstrap";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {ReactSession} from "react-client-session";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import useUser from "../hooks/useUser";

export function SecureCard(props) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
    const {user} = useUser();

    //Prevent the user from accessing the card if connected or not or if restricted
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(user);
        if (props.connected && props.restricted){
            if (!ReactSession.get("token") || user.rank !== "Administrator") navigate("/");
        }
        else if (props.connected){
            if (!ReactSession.get("token")) navigate("/");
        }
        else if (!props.connected){
            if (ReactSession.get("token")) navigate("/");
        }
        setValid(true);
    }, []);

    if(!valid)
        return null;

    return (
        <Card>
            <Card.Header><h2>{props.title}</h2></Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>
                {props.children}
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

**How SecureCard is called**

```
<SecureCard title="Web Admin" connected={true} restricted={true}></SecureCard>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [why images of code are bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Ok, I'ill change that right away!

Comment: Your secure card isn't looking at user to decide where to navigate. It's looking at its props. So don't forget to post how the props are set for that.

Comment: I updated my post with how I call SecureCard

Comment: Okay, so without a code sandbox I can't be SURE but you're manually setting props and then using context user in the useEffect. But the useEffect has no dependencies (the empty array) either place I see it. So it will only run once - when the component is mounted.

Comment: What is `useUser`? And if it is a context consumer is it being used within a defined context?

Comment: I understood what was my error with @Nikki9696 anwser, I haven't read what useEffect exactly do in detail so I didn't really understand what the deps of a useEffect where. Now I understand and it was all because of that. I added the requiered deps and it's now working. Thanks you  again!